# Div not scrolling in column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/yXOvGqsmzZ) here and in the right side column I've created some panels in a div. I'm trying to get it so that the panels scroll inside the column, but not the whole page (I don't want the header or footer to scroll above and below the panels), but for some reason the 'overflow-y: scroll' is disable or not working!

Here is my code

```css
html,body,.container {
    height:calc(100% - 17px);
}
.container {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0; /*set left/right padding according to needs*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

.col-md-3 {   
    background: pink;
}
.col-md-9 {
    background: yellow;   
}

.row .no-float {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
header, footer {
            text-align: center;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
            background: white;
        }

        footer {
            border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-float">Navigation</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 no-float" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <header>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Events</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hosts</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Teachers</button>
                </div>
            </header>
            
            <div id="eventsContainer" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Events</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hosts</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Teachers</button>
                </div>
            </footer> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here i can see lot of div..

Comment: Which one you want will be scrolling?

Comment: The only div I want to scroll is the div that has id = "eventsContainer", I've given it overflow-y: scroll

Comment: ok wait @user1186050

Comment: ya sure @user1186050

Comment: now you can check it

Comment: are you check that?

Comment: yes I checked bu the bootply shows the whole page scrolling

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the `height` to `#eventsContainer` to make it scroll. So use the CSS's `calc()` function. Like:

```
#eventsContainer {
  height: calc(100% - 122px); /* Total Height - Height of (header + footer) */
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
#eventsContainer {
  height: calc(100% - 122px);
}

html,body,.container {
    height:calc(100% - 17px);
}
.container {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0; /*set left/right padding according to needs*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

.col-md-3 {   
    background: pink;
}
.col-md-9 {
    background: yellow;   
}

.row .no-float {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
}
header, footer {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    background: white;
}

footer {
    border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 no-float">Navigation</div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 no-float" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
            <header>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Events</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hosts</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Teachers</button>
                </div>
            </header>
            
            <div id="eventsContainer" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        Basic panel example
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Events</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hosts</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Teachers</button>
                </div>
            </footer> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that overflow will only work when the content tries to exceed the container. In your example, the `#eventsContainer` has no set height, and due to the nature of HTML (which is to expand vertically to fit the content), the content was pushing out.

In order to achieve the scroll, your `#eventsContainer` has to have a set height.

However, since I assume you want this height to be dynamic, and not be something static like '300px', I whipped up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/62a28pj2/) to demonstrate absolute positioning to create a full-screen version without pushing outside.

Comment: Is there another way to accomplish this type of functionality? Depending on how many panels exist I will sometimes hide the footer! So I don't think calc (100% - 122px) will work for me.

Comment: well, I see it working in your example but it's not working on my page.

Comment: ya sure you can check now?

Comment: I checked it but the whole page scrolls

Comment: wait a min...you something wrong in footer..i will solve